# Best practice to load settings to the web application

Tags: javascript, json, electron

I have to load settings to an app when it's opened (*It's an [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/) application and I'm loading settings from the local json file*)

---

I'm loading settings right after the page is loaded:

```
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (document.readyState === 'complete'){
        loadSettings();
    }
}
```

but I think this is not the right way to do it because at first, the page sets inputs, like checkboxes, as they are in HTML file and only after that, changes their values again according to settings.
**I want to know what is the best practice to load the settings to a web app.**

Comment: What type of settings do you load?Can you use localStorage to save them?

Comment: Settings are just a local json file.

Comment: Does the main process need those settings?If not use the `localStorage` which is available on any renderer process

Comment: Yes I need settings just for render process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't claim to be familiar with Electron, but after looking at the documentation and [an example on github](https://github.com/electron/simple-samples/blob/master/activity-monitor/app.js), it appears that an electron convention is to use `app.on`/`app.once`

> ```
> var electron = require('electron') // http://electron.atom.io/docs/api
> var path = require('path')         // https://nodejs.org/api/path.html
> var url = require('url')           // https://nodejs.org/api/url.html
> var window = null
> // Wait until the app is ready
> electron.app.once('ready', function () {
>   // Create a new window
> });
> ```

In general, Javascript developers can subscribe to the [*readystatechange*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/readystatechange) event as you have done, as well as use [`document.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to subscribe to the [*DOMContentLoaded*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event:

```js
document.onreadystatechange = function(){
  console.log('document readystate: ',document.readyState);
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
  console.log('DOM Load: document readystate: ',document.readyState);
})
```

You might find [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13346746/1575353) interesting...